# Как вызвать функцию "arr.size() в степени n" раз

Tags: c++

Надо написать функцию следующего вида: на вход подаётся массив `arr`, число `n` и функция `foo`. Надо, чтобы над каждым из элементов массива `arr` функция выполнялась `arr.size() ^ n` раз, т.е. нужно `n` вложенных циклов. Можно сделать и один цикл от `1` `arr.size() ^ n`, но это число легко переполняется.

Например, при `n = 3` функция должна вырождаться в следующее:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < arr.size(); ++i1)
 for (int i2 = 0; i2 < arr.size(); ++i2)
  for (int i3 = 0; i3 < arr.size(); ++i3)
   foo(arr[i3]);
```

Comment: Ээээ... Вы хотите выполнять функцию столько раз, что это число вызывает переполнение?... :-O

Comment: @Harry ну для инта и массива всего из 2 элементов, переполнение уже  при 2^32+ будет; суть в том, как эти циклы размножить вообще

Comment: @user239635 в распространённых моделях данных `int * int` поместится в `long long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекурсия, она спасает и не в таких ситуациях :)

```
int total = 0;

void foo(int&)
{
    ++total;
    // do stuff
}

void cycle(int&a, void (*foo)(int&), int n, int level = 0)
{
    if (level == n)
        foo(a);
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) cycle(a,foo,n,level+1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    cycle(i,foo,4);
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

Идея понятна? или дописать для конкретно массива?